# Conditions for Ramanujan's Master Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, mellin-transform

I would like to apply Ramanujan's Master Theorem (RMT) to formally justify some integrals that I have been using. The source for the proof of the RMT that I have is Hardy's book on Ramanujan's work. The formal statement of the RMT can be found in https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.704.4327&rep=rep1&type=pdf as Theorem 3.2. In Hardy's book, he says that the growth condition on $\varphi$ (and in particular the requirement $A < \pi$) is 'natural', but insufficient in many practical applications, where apparently $A=\pi$ is the best bound available.

In almost all practical applications I have seen, the formal statement of the RMT is more or less ignored and it is applied 'blindly' to derive a bunch of interesting integrals.

**How can one generically check that the growth condition on $\varphi$ is satisfied? Is there a simpler condition which implies this kind of growth?**

Specifically, I am interested in proving entry 3.252-10 in Gradsteyn & Rhyzik: [http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf)

If I expand the function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+2x\cos t +x^2)^{\alpha_2}}; \quad (\alpha_2 >0)  $$
in terms of Gegenbauer polynomials and 'blindly' apply the RMT, I get the correct answer (after some trivial manipulations and using the generalized definition of Gegenbauer polynomials in terms of ${}_2F_1$, which can also be found in the above link).

To meet the conditions of the RMT, I would need to prove that the function
$$ \phi(s) = C^{\alpha_2}_{s}(\cos t) $$
satisfies said growth condition as a function of $s$, where $0 < t < \pi$. I don't know how to approach this.

Edit: for completeness' sake, the growth condition reads: for some $0<\delta<1$ and $s=v+iw$ in the half-plane $v \geq -\delta$  we have $$|\phi(v+iw)| \leq C \exp(Pv + A|w|)$$

for some $P$ and $A<\pi$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For a start, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.07204.pdf seems to contain some useful expansions for my specific case of $\phi(s)$. I can't quite fill in the details myself, but if someone can turn this into an answer I would be very thankful!

Comment: I was about to suggest that paper. What are the conditions on $\alpha_2$ and $s$?

Comment: I stated the conditions on $s$. We can assume $\text{Re}(\alpha_2) > 0$.

Comment: In the expansion (1.28) for $C_s^{(\alpha )} (\cos t)$ the main contribuation is coming from $$
\left| {\cos (\gamma _{\alpha ,s,n} )} \right| \le \cosh (\Im \gamma _{\alpha ,s,n} ) \ll _\alpha  e^{t\left| w \right|} .
$$ I assume $0<t<\pi$. The gamma ratios behave like $$
\left| {\frac{{\Gamma (s + \alpha  - n)}}{{\Gamma (s + 1)}}} \right| \sim \left| s \right|^{\alpha  - n - 1} ,
$$ which does not really effect the behaviour in $|w|$. You have to fill in the nasty details.

Comment: I see. You refer to (1.28), but I don't have $\text{Im}(\nu)$ bounded. I should use (1.29) instead, it seems. Do you agree? In any case, it seems that I am able to satisfy the constraints needed, correct? (Indeed we have $0 < t < \pi$ which I did not mention, sorry).

Comment: Indeed, you are right. The anaysis is similar though.